# Trying to insert data from a file into mongodb using node.js. Data inserts but the localhost page does not load showing my end message?

Tags: javascript, node.js, mongodb, insert, localhost

This is my code:
Data is inserted but the localhost page does not load. The last message "Inserted" is also not printed. Any problem that you see? Thanks

```js
var http = require('http');
var fs = require('fs');
var readline = require('readline');
var url = require('url');
const MongoClient = require('mongodb').MongoClient;
const url2 = "mongodb+srv://ramaty01:password@cluster0-hi4fv.mongodb.net/test? 
retryWrites = true & w = majority ";

http.createServer(function(req, res) {

  if (req.url === '/favicon.ico') {
    res.writeHead(200, {
      'Content-Type': 'image/x-icon'
    });
    res.end();
    console.log('favicon requested');
    return;
  }
  var qobj = url.parse(req.url, true).query;
  var filename = qobj.name;
  var myFile = readline.createInterface({
    input: fs.createReadStream(qobj.name)
  });

  myFile.on('line', function(line) {
    var full = "" + line;
    var split_array = full.split(",");
    MongoClient.connect(url2, {
      useUnifiedTopology: true
    }, function(err, db) {
      if (err) {
        console.log("Error: " + err);
        return;
      }

      var dbo = db.db("Company");
      var collection = dbo.collection('companies');

      var newData = {
        "company_name": split_array[0],
        "stock_ticker": split_array[1]
      };
      collection.insertOne(newData, function(err, res) {
        if (err) {
          console.log("Error: " + err);
          return;
        }
        console.log("new document inserted");
      });

      console.log("Success!");
      myFile.on("end", function() {
        console.log("end of data");
        db.close();
      });
      //db.close();
    });
  });

  res.write("Inserted");

}).listen(8080);
```

Comment: Try console.log `newData` right before you  insert it and see what ot says?

Comment: @AvivLo it works for insertion but the localserver does not load

Answer (score 0):

Try adding res.end() after writing to the response. Something like this:

// Write to database

`res.write("Inserted");
res.end();`

Kindly tell me if it works...